# Weighted Least Squares - Categorical Data vs. Numerical Data

Tags: statistics, least-squares, weighted-least-squares

[Over on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532266/weighted-least-squares-in-statsmodels-vs-numpy?noredirect=1#comment88081341_50532266), I am trying calculate the Weighted Least Squares (WLS) of a data set in a python library called Numpy as compared to using a library called Statsmodels. However, I noticed something very mysterious.

I have discovered that computing the WLS on **numerical data** *vs.* **categorical data** yields a completely different line of best fit. I understand that in the categorical example of **male** *vs.* **female**, with the values zero (0) and one (1) being assigned respectively, it is wrong to compare the dummy variables of the male and female category groups (e.g. male < female because 0 < 1) as we could have chosen any numbers for these groups, but...

**How does the math change?** Why do you get a different line of best fit when just treating everything as numerical data than when having categorical data?

[As reported here on slide 2](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/canty/teaching/stat3a03/Lectures7.pdf), the WLS estimates for the parameters of the line of best fit are found by minimizing the **weighted** [Residual Sum of Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) (RSS):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i(y_i-[\beta_0+\beta_1*x_i])^2 \\ parameters=\beta_0,\beta_1 \\ weights=\vec{w} \\ input=\vec{x} \\ output=\vec{y}$$

How does this change with categorical data? I am extremely confused about the math behind including categorical data in the calculations. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Judging by your question that you linked in SO, I think this is a question of what `statsmodels` is doing. The math in both cases is identical.

Comment: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249892/wildly-different-r2-between-statsmodels-linear-regression-and-sklearn-linear/249897) might be relevant.